# Resize the circles of the radio buttons

Tags: css

I used a YII framework in my project (website), I used many styles, many queries, for mobiles also, but I faced a little problem: I added the buttons successfully.
But the button itself is so small, and the label is big, the circle of the button when I click it to choose this button, is too small, I give a style for the label, but I need to resize the circle itself.

Here is the PHP code:

```
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'frequency_id',  

       CHtml::listData(Frequency::model()->findAll(), 'ID',    

   'frequency'),array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline;width:150px'), 



          'template'=>"{input} {label}", 'separator'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')) ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'frequency_id'); ?>
```

The question is can I resize the circle of the radio bottom, also what is the modification on my code will be?

Comment: I do not think the traditional radio button can be styled, but you can use something like jQuery-UI or jquery-mobile, to add a fancy styled "radio button" div, while the real one is hidden and controlled by javascript.

Comment: Btw a PHP example is really pointless here, you'd better shown the CSS and generated HTML.

Comment: Apparently, there is also a pure CSS solution: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons aren't directly style-able. They're an OS dependent element.

If you can hide the radio button and style elements adjacent to it you can mimic the effect though.
If you hide the checkbox itself with `display:none` and style an element beside it you can swap out images of checked and unchecked boxes.

For example: a selector like `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span` will allow you to style a `span` inside a `label` that is directly beside a checked `checkbox`. This would be your *on* state, *off* would be `input[type="checkbox"] + label span`

The main problem with this approach is that the `:checked` selector isn't fully supported across the board. IE 8 and under will not show any checkbox at all.

There may also be javascript solutions.

Comment: mmmm , but i found a solution as enable the size in the array

Comment: <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'frequency_id',  

       CHtml::listData(Frequency::model()->findAll(), 'ID',    

   'frequency',array('style'=>'width:50px; height:50px ')),array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline;width:150px'), 



          'template'=>"{input} {label}", 'separator'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')) ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'frequency_id'); ?>

Comment: this is the solutionh ,loooooooooooool